# How to debug the browser compatibility issues with JQuery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tabs

- Jquery tabs are being displayed as vertical list in an accordion in
  IE6.
- But it works fine in Firefox and IE 7. Any solution?

I am using Jquery tabs within a jquery accordion. It works and displays fine IE7 and firefox but not in IE6. The tabs are appearing as vertical lists. The tabs do work.

Comment: isn't that a good idea to Update IE? :)

Comment: What's the render mode the browser chooses for this page? (honestly I don't know how to check the render mode in IE6 :(  loading the page and then writing javascript:alert(document.compatMode) in the url bar might work)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI 1.9 release should NOT have this issue, try to use the latest version.

As [jQuery UI 1.10 Upgrade Guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-support-for-ie6) suggests:

> **Removed support for IE6**
>
> IE6 usage has dropped to a low enough point that jQuery UI no longer
>   finds it necessary to support. As of 1.10.0, some portions of jQuery
>   UI may not work properly in IE6. If you need to continue to support
>   IE6, use the latest jQuery UI 1.9 release.